# redirect to another form if email exists

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-1.9

I want to implement an invitation feature where user will fill in email address and their email will be saved to database. If they again fill in email address and request for invitation, they should be redirected to another form(ReferForm) so they can refer other.

Here is my code

```
class InviteForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"), required=True)

    def save(self, email):
        print('email', email)
        print ('############')
        if (Invitation.objects.get(email=email)):
            return True
        invitation = Invitation.objects.create(email=email)
        return invitation

class RequestInvitation(FormView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form_class = InviteForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        invite_instance = form.save(email)
        if invite_instance == True:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/refer-form')
        invite_instance.invited_by_email_address = self.request.user
        invite_instance.custom_invite_code = get_custom_invite_code()
        invite_instance.save()
        messages.success(self.request, '{0} has been invited'.format(email))
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # messages.error(self.request, '{0}'.format(form.errors))
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

I get an error inside form save function where i have queried for email existence. However i get an error

> Invitation matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

use `get_or_create`

```
invitation, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
return invitation if created else True
```

Comment: I already did that but i always get created false. Is it because i am not using modelForm

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it but is it the best way?

```
class InviteForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"), required=True)

    def save(self, email):
        try:
            invitation = Invitation.objects.get(email=email)
            return None
        except Invitation.DoesNotExist:
            invitation = Invitation.objects.create(email=email)
            return invitation


def form_valid(self, form):
      email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
      invite_instance = form.save(email)
      if invite_instance is None:
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/invitations/refer-invitation')
      invite_instance.invited_by_email_address = self.request.user
      invite_instance.custom_invite_code = get_custom_invite_code()
      invite_instance.save()
      messages.success(self.request, '{0} has been invited'.format(email))
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```